# Translating javascript json parse to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I had to change an application that was making a call clientside (JS) to get back data that comes back as JSON. I had to move the call server side, and I'm using rails to return the data.

To reference the object I need, with the object being returned called "data" I was able to call it JS like so:

data.photos[0].tags[0].mouth_left.x

I'm very new to rails, I have the call populating a variable called face_values, I think I should call to_json on it next, but how do I reference the arrays and nested objects within?

Even a point in the right direction would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parsing JSON in Rails is as follows:

```
parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json_string)
```

or check out this [link](http://flori.github.com/json/)

They claim they are 21.5x faster than ActiveSupport::JSON.decode

Comment: I find the following link useful to explain the difference between the json gem and the Active Support library http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/